# PHP to Android Studio with MSSQL server

Tags: android

I have some issues with my program about an error with the Android response between PHP and SQLSRV.

The problem is, I'm unable to access "Login Activity" when I press the Register button.

PHP code:

```
<?php include('connect.php'); 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
print_r($_POST); $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.[user] (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$params = array(&$name, &$age, &$username, &$password);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} 
$response = array();
$response['success'] = true; 
echo json_encode ($response);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Android code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        eLog.d("response", response );
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if(success){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                Register.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

```
com.example.cursoft.loginregistra.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:51)
 06-22 14:42:24.125 10198-10198/com.example.cursoft.loginregistra W/System.err:     at com.example.cursoft.loginregistra.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:45)
 06-22 14:42:24.125 10198-10198/com.example.cursoft.loginregistra W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
 06-22 14:42:24.125 10198-10198/com.example.cursoft.loginregistra W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
 06-22 14:42:24.125 10198-10198/com.example.cursoft.loginregistra W/System.err:
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: First of all, your log cat states that the error is located on LoginActivity.java at line 51

Comment: this is also the error 06-23 13:59:29.309 17372-17372/com.example.cursoft.loginregistra W/System.err:     at com.example.cursoft.loginregistra.Register$1$1.onResponse(Register.java:55)
06-23 13:59:29.309 17372-17372/com.example.cursoft.loginregistra W/System.err:     at com.example.cursoft.loginregistra.Register$1$1.onResponse(Register.java:49)

Comment: Is there a typo in this line `eLog.d("response", response );`?